# Rewriting $x$ in terms of trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given equation
$$8x(1-2x^2)(8x^4-8x^2 + 1) = 1,$$
how can one rewrite x in terms of trigonometric function?

Answer (score 2):

If you put $x=\cos\theta$ the equation is equivalent to $$8\cos \theta(-\cos 2\theta)(\cos 4\theta)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Here:
$$
x = \tan^4 y - \sin(\sin(u - \cos v)).
$$

I have rewritten $x$ in terms of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Thank's, but may I know how did you get this result?

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity This answer is just a joke. I am making the point that your question makes no sense :) It is easy to rewrite $x$ in terms of trigonometric functions. Maybe your real question is, **solve for $\boldsymbol{x}$?**

Comment: I see. :) Well, it is a larger exercise, and I have to rewrite x in term of trig functions to derive some properties in certain interval. And I was kinda uncertain what did they mean by this rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two sides factors as $-(2x+1)(8x^3-6x+1)(8x^3-4x^2-4x+1)$.  Of course $x=-1/2$ is the root of the first factor.
$$ 8 \cos(t)^3 - 6 \cos(t) + 1 = 2 \cos(3t) + 1$$
which is $0$ when $\cos(3t) = -1/2 = \cos(2\pi/3)$,
so the roots of the second factor are $\cos(2\pi/9)$, $\cos(8\pi/9)$, $\cos(14\pi/9)$.

When $x = \dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{3} \cos(t)+\dfrac{1}{6}$
$$ 8x^3-4x^2-4x+1 = {\frac {14\,\sqrt {7}\cos \left( 3\,t \right) }{27}}+{\frac{7}{27}}$$

and this gives you trigonometric expressions for roots of the third factor:
$$ \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{3} \cos(\arccos(-1/(2\sqrt{7}))/3 + 2 \pi j/3),\; j=0,1,2$$